# How to replace struct c++

Tags: c++, std

I have the following struct

```
struct LetterFreq{
  char letter;
  double freq;
};
```

Now I am trying to create a std:list of these...

```
std::list<LetterFreq> freqList;
LetterFreq f = {'A',.08167};
freqList.push_back(f);
f =  {'B',.01492};
freqList.push_back(f);
```

However, when I try compiling I get...

```
error: expected expression
```

If I change to something like...

```
std::list<LetterFreq> freqList;
LetterFreq f = {'A',.08167};
freqList.push_back(f);
LetterFreq f2 =  {'B',.01492};
freqList.push_back(f2);
```

It seems to work, but I don't really want it like that. I would rather reuse the variable `f`.

Comment: Same "value"? Or same `variable`?

Comment: Same variable (pointer?) so the first time it has a letter A second time letter is B

Comment: you could always do `f.letter = 'B'; f.freq = 0.01492;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without C++ 11 you can do this:

```
struct LetterFreq{
  char letter;
  double freq;

  LetterFreq(char letter, double freq)
  : letter(letter), freq(freq)
  {}
};

f =  LetterFreq('B',.01492);
```

Comment: I will give this a shot I made my struct in a header file so not sure if this will work for me but we will see.

Comment: A little more code than I wanted but it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++11 available, you can use:

```
std::list<LetterFreq> freqList;
freqList.emplace_back('A', .08167);
freqList.emplace_back('B', .01492);
```

Or better yet, use initializer lists like this:

```
std::list<LetterFreq> freqList { {'A', .08167}, {'B', .01492} };
```

Answer (score 0):

The trap that you're falling in to, is that initialiser lists are done with the constructor.  In your second example, because you are creating new objects each time (and not an existing one), the compiler is invoking the constructor with your initialiser list.

In your first example, it would have to invoke the assignment operator which does *not* support initialiser lists and really, nor should it :)